# Do all NVIDIA graphics cards support CUDA?

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I have

```
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GL [Quadro K2200] [10de:13ba] (rev a2)
```

It appears that this supports CUDA, but I just wanted to confirm.

Do all NVIDIA graphics cards support CUDA?

Answer (score 2):

See https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus for a list of which CUDA release is supported by which card.  Your Quadro K2200, has a compute capability of 3.0.  Check the fine print on each CUDA release to see if that is sufficient, if not, drop back a release.